# Where did the Greeks get their word "bio" from?

Tags: etymology, greek, biology

Is it possible that it comes from the junction of the word: "bi" and the Greek letter" "Omega", literally translating to "two of everything"?

Comment: It was given to the Greeks by the [aliens who populated the earth](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/38568/were-humans-placed-on-earth-by-aliens).

Comment: @Hot Licks:  As the website says,  It is not enough to have a personal opinion. References are required. ;)

Comment: Why would omega "literary" translate as _everything_?

Comment: @Xanne - I'm sure if we search the works of Clarke, Asimov, Heinlein, Bradbury, Wells, and Adams we can find a suitable reference somewhere.

Comment: Most anything is possible but this is very unlikely given that it fits so exactly with phonetic derivation patterns with similar words in other Indo-European languages.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about Greek, not English.

Comment: Studying the origin of Greek words is kind of like learning about your grandparents or great-grandparents. It still provides us with information, does it not? Is it irrelevant to simply trace the etymology of our words back a few generations? We have traced many words all the way back to Sanskrit, like voice, smile, and serpent. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/serpent

Comment: Alpha and Omega always mean opposites: beginning-end, first-last, nothing-everything, etc. These terms are used in biblical related publications, mathematical terms, and even have scientific use, such as in biology and chemistry. "Zoe" and "bio" both mean life in Greek, but "bio" may have been the more poetic way of saying it because it relates to the story of Noah's Ark. Since he took two of everything, the word bio might have come to mean life in the sense of "continuing life on". It was probably a frequently talked about story of the time, so it could influence language a bit. Thoughts?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=bio https://books.google.com/books?id=HjKUiljUwcUC&pg=PA1055&lpg=PA1055&dq=alpha+and+omega+opposites+first+last&source=bl&ots=fejG2Wftdt&sig=a2m-RmFGRRvKMKi0kCxskJxKOBI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ58axzqrUAhWqqFQKHfwUCUcQ6AEIZjAN#v=onepage&q=alpha%20and%20omega%20opposites%20first%20last&f=false

Answer (score 1):

The prefix ***[bio-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bio-)*** appears to be derive from the PIE root *gwei- meaning "to live" :

> - word-forming element, especially in scientific compounds, meaning "life, life and," or "biology, biology and," or "biological, of or pertaining to living organisms or their constituents,"
> - ***from Greek bios "one's life, course or way of living, lifetime"*** (as opposed to zoe "animal life, organic life"),
> - **from PIE root **gwei- "to live."*** The correct usage is that in *biography,* but since c. 1800 in modern science it has been extended to mean "organic life," as *zoo-,* the better choice, is restricted in modern use to animal, as opposed to plant, life. ***Both are from the same PIE root.***

(Etymonline)

Comment: Related post on Linguistics SE: [What is the difference between Greek zōē and bios?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/16790)